# What will Saruman The White's role be in The Desolation of Smaug?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, saruman, desolation-of-smaug

I was wondering if anyone has any insight on this? As far as I'm aware, The White Council did attack Dol Guldur, But will Saruman be leading this attack and do you think he'll have quite a big role in this storyline? Will there be any signs shown of Saruman searching for the ring? and will there be any signs of Saruman taking interest in his enemies Machines? (aka, wanting to industrialize Isengard?)

To me, I believe The Lord of the Rings simply could not have functioned how well it did without Saruman, I've always had a great interest in this character and it would be due and respectful to only have him as quite a large part/role in the upcoming Dol Guldur battle.

Comment: VTCing this as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: VTROing this because the movie is out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only hints we have are from the books. Although Saruman resisted attacking Dol Guldur initially, he did finally relent. Tolkien never said exactly who was in the White Council, nor exactly who attacked Dol Guldur, but I can virtually guarantee that Saruman was among them. If he had insisted on sitting out the attack, I don't think it would have taken 50+ more years for Gandalf to figure out his duplicity.

It's in Saruman's best interest to prevent his own plans from being discovered, which is why he didn't want Dol Guldur attacked. As long as Sauron was residing there, in secret, Saruman was more or less free to search for the ring on his own. As soon as Sauron revealed himself, the White Council would be forced to have other responsibilities (and it became that much more likely that Sauron would be openly looking for the ring).

So if the Council was going to attack Dol Guldur with or without him, his smartest action is to participate.

I wouldn't be surprised if Jackson's Saruman has different ideas, though.

Comment: Thank-you, I know Jackson has said that he is going a long with the notes that were left of a possible storyline for the White Council, as you say, there was no exact mention of who this council consisted of. Supposedly, The first Uruk(hai?) where seen in Dol Guldur, so it would be nice to see if Saruman does take any particular interest in the movie if these Uruk-hai are sighted (However I have read that they were discreetly removed from Dol Guldur without anyone knowing. I'm sure that no matter what, Christopher Lee will perfect the role any how.

Comment: "It's in Saruman's best interest to prevent his own plans from being discovered, which is why he didn't want Dol Guldur attacked. As long as Sauron was residing there, in secret, Saruman was more or less free to search for the ring on his own" I am reasonably certain that Saruman didn't know the ring wasn't lost forever until after the events of the Hobbit, so this entire section seems wrong.

Comment: There was obvious signs for him searching for it, it's said that while he was looking he found Isildurs corpse. It would be one of the logical reasons for Saruman wanting to hold off the attack.

Answer (score 1):

### Saruman the White does not appear or even get mentioned in the theatrical edition of the Desolation of the Smaug

However, he does get a very brief mention by Gandalf in the Extended Edition cut.

Beorn says there are rumors of the Witch King of Angmar being resurrected, and asks Gandalf if this is an indication that Sauron has returned. Gandalf replies that Saruman said such a thing was impossible.

> BEORN: I remember a time when a great evil ruled these lands. One powerful enough to raise the dead. If that enemy has returned to Middle-earth I would have you tell me.
>
> GANDALF: **Saruman the White** says it's not possible. The enemy was destroyed and will never return.
>
> BEORN: And what does Gandalf the Grey say?

He does have a role in the movies Dol Guldur battle, but that doesn't happen until the third movie, The Battle of the Five Armies.